# Change jQuery popup to appear on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a jQuery popup that will appear automatically when a webpage loads. Here is a working code for a popup which opens up with click on a button that I am using:

```
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

How do I write the code if I want the popup above to appear as specified? In this format if it's possible please:

```
$('[data-popup-close]').on('page-load', function(e)  {
```

Comment: Please do not add [solved] to questions when they are answered, the tick is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the popup as soon as the page is ready, [you simply pass the function to be executed to the JQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). There is no need for binding with `on`. Keep in mind that now that the function is invoked by a different object, `this` will be bound to `window` and not the `data-popup-close` element.

```
$(function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = $('[data-popup-close]').attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The popup appears as intended!

Comment: @JosefLundström No problem. Don't forget to up vote as well.